# JSON parsing into ListView Android

Tags: android, json

This is the JsonObject i get form parsing my url: `{"status":0,"items":"1333333454510|-7611868|-7222457"`

now i need to get the seperate numbers seperetly as `long`.

i also get an error if i try to convert it to string: `org.json.JSONException: Value 1333333454510|-7611868|-7222457 at items of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

How? Thanks

here is some code

```
JSONObject obj = JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL + "search", parameters);
String firstItem = obj.getJSONObject("items").toString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your `items` using `\\|`.

Example :

```
String items= "1333333454510|-7611868|-7222457" ; //here you got items

String[] _items=items.split("\\|");
```

Now iterate loop and convert it into long using `Long.ParseLong().`

**EDIT :**

As Ashwin said you need to use `json.getString("items");` to get items.

You can convert it into long using following code.

```
ArrayList<Long> longs=new ArrayList<Long>();


for(int i=0;i<_items.length;i++){
longs.add(Long.parseLong(_items[i]));
}
```

Comment: but i get an error: org.json.JSONException: Value 1333333454510|-7611868|-7222457at items of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: @Pheonix7 As Ashwin mention in his code. use json.getString().

Comment: nice!! 1 more thing. i need to do operations with these id's, like adding and subtracting. can i just do that on the longs values?

Comment: Yes you can do addition and subtraction on long values.

Comment: as these valuse are id's and they are all subtracted by each other could u show me how to rite this is code? thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42870/discussion-between-prince-and-pheonix7)

Answer (score 0):

Use Split function to separate.

parse json  to get items in items String

use jsonObject.getString instead of jsonObject.getJSONObject to avoid error.

```
String items= "1333333454510|-7611868|-7222457" ; 
String[] itemsArray =items.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String response= "{"status":0,"items":"1333333454510|-7611868|-7222457"}" ; // ie, response contains the string.

JsonObject json= new JsonObject(response);

String item=json.getString("items");
String [] items =item.split("|");
```

Will get 3 numbers in the items array.

Comment: json object should be like this. {"status":0,"items":"1333333454510|-7611868|-7222457"}

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here

```
  JSONObject obj = JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL + "search", parameters);
  String firstItem = obj.getJSONObject("items").toString();
```

so change it to

```
String firstItem = obj.getString("items").toString();
```

and then do split operations as suggested by others.

SO force always with you:)

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonObject json= new JsonObject(response);

String item=json.getString("items");
String [] items =item.split("|");
```